# Regiment map from Coxeter-Dynkin diagram

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polytopes

The following problem arises in the attempt to enumerate uniform polytopes:
Given a Wythoffian polytope, what are all other Wythoffian polytopes which use maximal subsets of its vertices and edges, and what are their incidences?
Here, maximal means that the polytope uses every edge in its subspace.

Comment: Can you give es example of such a configuration?

Comment: What do you mean by configuration?

Comment: A Wythoffian polytope and another Wythoffian polytope using a maximal set of vertices/edges of the former one, and their incidences. I am asking because do not really understand what you are asking for in your question.

Comment: Let’s use the rhombicuboctahedron. The other polytopes are one set of vertices, two sets of line segments, one set of triangles, and two sets of squares. The vertices are singly incident to both sets of edges, the first set of line segments are singly incident to both sets of squares and the set of octagons, and the second set of line segments are singly incident to the set of triangles, the second set of squares, and the set of octagons.